# Why buttons of keyboard changed its places in openSUSE KDE

Tags: kde, opensuse, keyboard-layout

Why buttons of keyboard changed its places in openSUSE KDE

For Example, when I click <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> don't print `@` it's print this "

Comment: This is likely due to the keyboard layout being set to a UK layout on a US keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Your keyboard layout is wrong, which means that the keyboard is incorrectly mapped to different symbols than those pictured on the keys.

To change the layout in KDE, start KRunner using the correct key combination (by default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), type in `keyboard`, and open keyboard settings. Go to Layouts, make sure that the "Configure layouts" checkbox is ticked, and check that the current keyboard layout matches your current keyboard. If it does not, change it to an appropriate one.

[image: Keyboard layout settings]

Answer (score -2):

if using yast, search keyboard. There, you can change the layout from UK to US.